# How to launch .exe file with run

Tags: autoit

I tried to launch a program with Run & Runwait but the program don't appear

Run & Runwait command

```
Run('R:\Windows\Bureau\Hoop Bot\lib\scrcpy-win64\scrcpy-noconsole.exe')
```

Or

```
Run('@Scriptdir\lib\scrcpy-win64\scrcpy-noconsole.exe')
```

same with runwait

No error messages

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the working dir for the program.

```
Run('R:\Windows\Bureau\Hoop Bot\lib\scrcpy-win64\scrcpy-noconsole.exe', 'R:\Windows\Bureau\Hoop Bot\lib\scrcpy-win64\')
```

And if you are using @ScriptDir it should go like this:

```
Run(@Scriptdir & '\lib\scrcpy-win64\scrcpy-noconsole.exe', 'R:\Windows\Bureau\Hoop Bot\lib\scrcpy-win64\')
```